# How do I pass formated (\n \t) text to a java command line

Tags: java, batch-file

I need to pass a formatted string in a command line so that the input text is presented formatted in a JFrame:

```
Hello
The sun is shinning!
```

How do I put a '\n' in a Windows batch file?

```
java -cp . Test "Hello\nThe sun is shinning!"
```

I cannot change the program, it is expecting a string as a command line parameter to be shown in a TextBox, and I want to pass multiple lines.

Thanks

Comment: It may be helpful to tell us what you have tried already.

Comment: I tried: 
- java -cp . Test "Hello\nThe sun is shinning!"
- java -cp . Test "Hello
The sun is shinning!"
- java -cp . Test < 1.txt

I really don't know how to insert \n character as a parameter in a windows batch file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

Bear in mind that the "`\n`" escape sequence is only recognised by the Java compiler, and doesn't mean anything otherwise.

So what you have here is a Windows batch file language issue, and as far as I know there's no way to put an embedded NL in the parameters in Windows.

What you *could* do, however, is solve the problem with "`\n`" mentioned above, and actually have your code recognise the escape sequence:

```
param = param.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

The backslash character is quoted twice in the first string, since you actually want to match a literal backslash character.

There's also a function in the Apache Commons library that'll do this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.*;
param = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(param);
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments, and I totally agree with you if I could change the code. The problem is that I cannot change the Java program, I need to pass formatted string in the command line.

Comment: any reason you can't write a wrapper (using the above functions) that then invokes the real program with the unescaped parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly but you should be able to do it using `echo` and `&&`.
Try this:

```
java -cp . Test (echo Hello&&echo The sun is shining!)
```

A tab doesn't need escaping - you can put it directly into your batch file.